# What parts of a SQL query are allowed to be parameterized?

Tags: sql

For instance, this is generally allowed:

```
sql.execute("select * from some_table where some_column=@parameter", parameter=5);
```

But not this:

```
sql.execute("select * from @which_table where some_column=5", which_table="some_table");
```

Having not tested all possible combinations.... Is this:

```
sql.execute("select @which_column from some_table", which_column="some_column");
```

Or this:

```
sql.execute("select some_column*@multiplier from some_table", multipler=5);
```

Or....

What is the general rule for determining whether some part of a query is parameterizable, and why?

(I realize that this may have different answers with respect to different DB engines and adapters for different languages, but I've noticed that there are general trends)

Comment: In short, you can parameterize a value but you can't parameterize an object like a table, a column, or a database. When you need dynamic columns and tables it generally points to bad database design (but not always). You'll have to write some code to dynamically generate your SQL in those cases.

Comment: Oracle: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables

Comment: In short: everything that will **not** change the query plan when the parameters are changed. So: schema/table/column names, operators, (aggregate) function names can not be parametrised (and would need dynamic SQL) Maybe I forgot a few...

Comment: Per your examples given; `1` and `4` are valid, while `2` and `3` are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers and keywords are not parameterizable.  This includes:

- Columns names
- Table names
- Schema names
- Database names
- Operators
- Function names
- Keywords

The basic idea is that the query is being compiled, and the compiled version has parameters.  The query cannot be compiled when any of the above elements are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterizable anything in a query but not at run time. If you set up like this:
@sql = 'select '+ @column +' from '+ @table +' '

EXEC (@sql)

You can parameterize everything

So you need to create the sql statement first and after that execute it. That is the way I usually do it.

Hope that helps